# General mysql table design advice

Tags: mysql

i have got some specific data set which regards to the SLA (Service level agreement) for a particular work as follows. 
here x  represents no of hours. 
once a task completed within given time range specific level is giving as follows.

> ```
> Level 1 --- > x>=500
>
> Level 2 --- > 500> x >=400
>
> Level 3 --- > 400> x  >=300
>
> Level 4 --- > 300> x >=200 
>
> Level 5 --- > 100 > x >=200
> ```

i required to get the level of particular task eg:-
if x is 252, that task is level 4.

i have designed the table in below format, but i wont give the capability to get the level for any x value. kindly suggest me the best/ accurate mysql table design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your table design implicitly assumes an order. In a relational database there is no order to the rows. None.

So a better design would be these columns:

```
serviceLevel
minimumHours 
maximumHours
```

It then becomes very easy to retrieve the service level:

```
SELECT serviceLevel 
FROM <table> 
WHERE <hours> BETWEEN minimumHours AND maximumHours;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing both a lower and upper bound for each level, e.g.

```
Level | lower | upper
L1    | 500   | NULL
L2    | 400   | 500
L3    | 300   | 400
L4    | 200   | 300
L5    | 100   | 200
```

Now if you wanted to run your suggested query and search for `x = 252` you could do this:

```
SET @x=252;

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    @x >= lower AND
    (@x < upper OR upper IS NULL);
```